# Use a values of list to filter Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With python Pandas, I'm trying to filter out the data that contains the specified value in the array, I try to use python `in` to filter value, but it's not working, I want to know if there is a way to achieve such a function without looping

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], [1, 2, 3]]})
df = 1 in df['custom_test_type']

    A   B
0   1   [1, 2, 3]
1   2   [2, 3]
2   3   [3]
3   4   [1, 2, 3]
```

I'm try to filter 1 in row B, so expected output will be:

```
    A   B
0   1   [1, 2, 3]
3   4   [1, 2, 3]
```

but the output always be `True`

due to my limited ability, Any help or explanation is welcome! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop/list comprehension:

```
out = df[[1 in l for l in df['B']]]
```

A pandas version would be more verbose and less efficient:

```
out = df[df['B'].explode().eq(1).groupby(level=0).any()]
```

Output:

```
   A          B
0  1  [1, 2, 3]
3  4  [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, and I use pandas to improve performance, so want to know is it have some possible, Don't go through with for loops

Comment: Hi @mozway, If my data has a thousand columns, it would be more verbose and less efficient?

Comment: Here you don't have a choice, you cannot vectorize operations with a Series of lists. The list comprehension is very likely your best option.